# How to extract JAD file from COD file?

Tags: blackberry, jad

I provided a JAR file and a JAD file to the Blackberry's RAPC compiler. It produced a COD file. **The JAD file constains business logic related properties** (in opposition to classics properties like MIDlet-Name, etc) that I am trying to extract.

**Assuming one only has access to the COD file, is there a way to extract the JAD file from this COD file ?**

PS: I don't have access to the JAD given to the RAPC. Hence the question :)

PS2: Links/turotials/samples about how to create a JAD file for Blackberry don't answer the question.

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No.

(filling up to 30 characters)

Answer (score 1):

You can make your own JAD manually or do this by using "**BlackBerry Desktop Manager**":

http://www.ehow.com/how_7846156_create-jad-cod-alx.html

And here is a sample for JAD:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
RIM-COD-Module-Name: YourProjectName
RIM-COD-Module-Dependencies: net_rim_cldc,net_rim_pdap,net_rim_bbapi_invoke
MIDlet-Jar-Size: 133911__your_JAR_size_in_byte
MIDlet-1: ,img/icon.png,
RIM-COD-Creation-Time: 1319628844__maybe_unneccessary
MIDlet-Jar-URL: YourProjectName.jar
RIM-COD-URL: YourProjectName.cod
RIM-COD-Size: 45832__your_COD_size_in_byte
MicroEdition-Configuration: CLDC-1.1
MIDlet-Version: 1.0.0
MIDlet-Name: YourProjectName
MIDlet-Vendor: BlackBerry Developer
MicroEdition-Profile: MIDP-2.0
RIM-MIDlet-Flags-1: 0
```

Comment: Links/turotials/example about how to create a JAD file for Blackberry don't answer the question. I must extract the one used when calling RAPC.

Comment: @DavidAndreoletti: so what do you need here? A JAD file to pass as an argument to RAPC? or you need it for OTA purpose?

Comment: A JAD and a JAR have been provided to RAPC compiler. RAPC produces a COD file. JAD and JAR file have been deleted as part of a build process (not done by RAPC). Fior sake of simplicity, it is impossible to get/regeneate the original JAD/JAR files used. 

Now, I need find a way to get the JAD file from the COD file generated.

In other words, I give you only a COD file (asuming it was build from a JAD and a JAR), is there a way to extract the JAD file used to produce the COD file ?

Comment: the problem is clearer now. I've faced this problem before, and I've also suggested a snippet of JAD in the above answer. That was how I resolved it. Have you tried it?

Comment: And also, the snippet comes from a jad file of my small project. I eliminated some lines which I think they are unnecessary.